# Vanishing of higher direct images of a composition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

In a paper I am studying we have the following situation.

Let $S$ be the spectrum of a Dedekind domain, and let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be scheme of finite type over $S$, where $X$ and $Y$ are smooths and $Z$ is normal.

We are given morphisms (over $S$) $f \colon X \to Y$ and $g \colon Y \to Z$. We know that $f$ is finite, flat, and generically étale and that $g$ is proper.

We have a divisor $D$ on $Y$ such that $-D$ is effective and we want to prove that
$$
R^i (g \circ f)_\ast (\mathcal O_X(f^\ast D)) = 0
$$
for all $i > 0$. The natural idea is of course to use the Leray spectral sequence, that degenerates since $f$ is finite, so the problem reduces to the study of
$$
R^i g_\ast (f_\ast \mathcal O_X(f^\ast D)),
$$
that is a locally free sheaf on $Y$ of rank equal to the degree of $f$.

The thing I do not understand is that in the paper they prove that
$$
R^i g_\ast (\mathcal O_Y(D)) = 0
$$
for all $i > 0$ and they say that this suffices. I do not understand why this is enough. The sheaves $\mathcal O_Y(D)$ and $f_\ast \mathcal O_X(f^\ast D)$ are obliviously related in some way, but I do not see why the vanishing of the higher direct images of the first should implies the vanishing of the higher direct images of the second.

Comment: What is the paper you are reading ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer:

The push-pull (or projection) formula says that $f_*(\mathcal E \otimes f^* \mathcal F) = f_*\mathcal E \otimes \mathcal F,$ if $\mathcal F$ is locally free of finite rank on the target, and $\mathcal E$ is coherent on the source.
(See the exercises in Ch. II.5 of Hartshorne.)

In your particular case, it gives that $f_*(\mathcal O_X(f^* D) )=
(f_*\mathcal O_X)(D).$

Now $f_*\mathcal O_X$ is locally free of finite rank on $Y$; its rank
being equal to the degree of $f$.

If it were actually free (even locally on $Z$, i.e. if its restrictions
to $g^{-1}(U)$ for $U$ the members of some open cover of $Z$), then we
could reduce to computing $Rg_* \mathcal O_Y(D).$  But I don't see why that
should be true, so I don't see how the reduction to $O_Y(D)$ is being made.